# Pagination problem (plugin wp-pagenavi) with a custom post type?

Tags: templates, htaccess, plugins, pagination

I am currently developing a WordPress website with a custom post_type called "music".
I use the plugin wp-pagenavi to paginate content "music".

When I link on the first page, it's OK (see link below)
http://carbonpaper-dev.imperatorium.org/music/page/1

But when I link on the 2nd page:
http://carbonpaper-dev.imperatorium.org/music/page/2
the expected content is printed, but the template displayed is not the one related to the "music" `post_type/page` as the first page do but the one related to classic "posts" (not the same sidebar, no inclusion of music playback on click. ..)

Here is my .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-F
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-D
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Should I change this file? otherwise how to fit the extension `wp-pagenavi` with a custom post_type? or what should be the name for the file `{filename}.php` in order to respect hierarchy template?

Thank you for your reply, and apologies for my English, I'm French...

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the loop code.

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'music',
    'paged' => $paged
) ); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

or try this

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'music',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'orderby'=> 'menu_order',   
                    'order'=> 'DESC',
                    'paged' => $paged,
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'caller_get_posts'=> 1
                );                      

                $temp = $wp_query;  // assign original query to temp variable for later use
                $wp_query = null;
                $wp_query = new WP_Query();
                $wp_query->query($args);            

                while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();?>
```

Comment: can you explain what you did and why this should work?